# Media query with default style doesn't work as intended

Tags: css, media-queries

Here's my code:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .content {padding:4px;}
}   

@media (min-width:481px){
    .content {padding:10px;}
}
```

It works properly. But, it doesn't work as I intend when I change it like the below:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .content {padding:4px;}
}

.content {padding:10px;}
```

I intended to make ".content {padding:10px}" a default style. Only screen width less than equal to 480px uses ".content {padding:4px}".

Comment: Put the last line before the media query.

Comment: change the order..right normal query first

Answer (score 2):

With the default style last as in your example, it will override anything that has already been set. CSS is processed from top to bottom and any properties specified more than once will take the *last* specified value.

Therefore, put the default style *first*. This way if the `@media` query matches, it will override the already-set default style of 10px.

```
.content {padding:10px;}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .content {padding:4px;}
}
```

Comment: OMG.. That simple rule!! Thank u so much!